# IOS Swift3 DES,ECB,Padding Encryption

Tags: ios, swift

Below is my android java code, actually how to write this in IOS Swift3?

```
 final SecretKey key = new SecretKeySpec(keyBytes, "DESede");

 final Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("DESede/ECB/PKCS5Padding");

 cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);

 final byte[] cipherText = cipher.doFinal(plainTextBytes);
```

Comment: 3DES-ECB (DESede is 3DES) is really not secure, especially 2-key 3DES. If at all possible update to AES-CBC with a random IV.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find an AES or DES Common Crypto example here on SO and make changes as necessary to 3DES. Be sure the key is 24-bytes.

Change:

- algorithm: `CCAlgorithm3DES`
- mode: `kCCModeECB`
- options: `ccPKCS7Padding`

If the key is 16-bytes it is two-key 3DES, duplicate and append the first 8-bytes to the end of the key to create a 24-byte key.

Note: `DESede` known as 3DES or Tripple-DES.

3DES is really not secure, especially 2-key 3DES. If at all possible update to AES-CBC with a random IV.

Here is untested Swift 3  (Should also work with Swift4)code, note the warning about the key length above:

```
func trippleDESCrypt(data:Data, keyData:Data, ivData:Data, operation:Int) -> Data? {
    let cryptLength = size_t(data.count + kCCBlockSize3DES)
    var cryptData = Data(repeating:0, count:cryptLength)
    var numBytesEncrypted :size_t = 0

    let keyLength             = keyData.count
    let algoritm: CCAlgorithm = UInt32(kCCAlgorithm3DES)
    let options:  CCOptions   = UInt32(kCCOptionPKCS7Padding | kCCModeECB)

    let cryptStatus = cryptData.withUnsafeMutableBytes {cryptBytes in
        data.withUnsafeBytes {dataBytes in
            ivData.withUnsafeBytes {ivBytes in
                keyData.withUnsafeBytes {keyBytes in
                    CCCrypt(CCOperation(operation),
                            algoritm,
                            options,
                            keyBytes, keyLength,
                            ivBytes,
                            dataBytes, data.count,
                            cryptBytes, cryptLength,
                            &numBytesEncrypted)
                }
            }
        }
    }

    if UInt32(cryptStatus) == UInt32(kCCSuccess) {
        cryptData.count = numBytesEncrypted
    }
    else {
        print("Error: \(cryptStatus)")
        return nil
    }

    return cryptData
}
```

As usual you need to have a Bridging Header file that contains the import:

```
#import <CommonCrypto/CommonCrypto.h>
```

and you need to include the framework:

```
Security.framework.
```

Comment: Really good answer!!! Finally I get the correct encryption value!!!
But I changed "kCCModeECB" to "kCCOptionECBMode".